# (JavaFX) How to set Pane background image

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX and I'm trying to set an image as background (both Pane and the image have the same resolution) but I can't get it to work.

Currently I tried to add this property:
`style="-fx-background-image: url('arena.png'); -fx-background-size: cover;"`

and to the various containers above I added this to set their background as transparent:
`style="-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"`

I also tried setting the background of the Pane to red:
`style="-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0);"` and it worked correctly

The two files are both located in the 'resources' folder of the project as seen in the [screen](https://imgur.com/a/a8Hjuew).

Comment: Due to a [moderator/volunteer strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderator-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-and?r=Saves_AllUserSaves) I will not be performing any content curation on this question.

Comment: Create a [BackgroundImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundImage.html) object and assign it as the [background property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#backgroundProperty).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.